# WP - How to get all the comment_post_ID in bulk comment approval

Tags: php, wordpress, file, comments, fopen

When I approve the comments in bulk, it only gets one `comment_post_ID`.
I need to get all the `comment_post_ID`.

This code:

```
add_action('transition_comment_status', 'my_approve_comment_callback', 10, 3);

function my_approve_comment_callback($new_status, $old_status, $comment) {

    if ($old_status != $new_status && $new_status == 'approved') {
        $my_file = fopen("/tmp/postidlist.txt", "w");

        $comment_id_2 = get_comment($comment->comment_ID);
        $comment_post_id = $comment_id_2->comment_post_ID;

        fwrite($my_file, $comment_post_id);
        fclose($my_file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually the problem lies in the [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) mode; you are using `w`
>   which stantds for write mode which overwrite the existing content, you
>   have to use `a` mode which is used for append content to the existing
>   file.

Replace this line

```
$my_file = fopen("/tmp/postidlist.txt", "w");
```

with this

```
$my_file = fopen("/tmp/postidlist.txt", "a");
```

Hope this helps!